# Firmata.SendString doesn't work with specific `char` variables

Tags: string, firmata

I have a Firmata sketch, that accepts string messages, partitions them and sends its' parts back to a Firmata client program. My problem is certainly at the sketch's side. The problem is that `Firmata.sendString(argument1)` and `Firmata.sendString(argument2)` methods don't send anything. More information is found in the sketch's code. How can I get the `sendString` methods to work?

```CPP
/*
 * This sketch accepts strings in the following form:
 * CMDn(arg1,arg2)
 * CMDn — command name,
 * arg1 и arg2 — unnecessary arguments.
 * Each argument's length can be from 1 to 4 characters,
 * They're saved to separate variables.
 *
 * This sketch sends back the parsed commands partially:
 * the command name, argument #1 (if present), argument #2 (if present)
 */


#include <Firmata.h>


void stringCallback(char *received) {
  //CMDn(arg1,arg2)
  //CMDn(arg1)
  //CMDn(1)
  //CMDn()
  //012345678901234
  //          11111

  //This scheme up there is just for 
  //understanding the indexes of the chars in the string
  //in its various possible variations

  //Let's declare all the necessary variables
  char methodName[5];
  char argument1[5];
  char argument2[5];
  byte commaLocation = 0;

  //If the received string doesn't match the strings' syntax,
  //send an error message
  if (!(received[4] == '(' && strlen(received) <= 15)) {
    Firmata.sendString("ERR;");
    return;
  }

  //Let's take the 0-3 chars in the string and send it back.
  //It's probably the command name
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    methodName[i] = received[i];
  }
  methodName[4] = '\0'; //does or doesn't the compiler add the terminator automatically?
  Firmata.sendString(methodName); //send it
  //This string is being sent without problems.


  //If there is some arguments in the string,
  //it is detectable if the string char 5 is not ')'/
  if (received[5] != ')') {
    //Lent's find out if the input string has a `comma`
    //inside the parentheses. If it does, it means that
    //there are two arguments in the string.

    Firmata.sendString("46 passed");    
    for (int i = 6; i < (strlen(received) - 1); i++) {
      //If there is a comma, save its' index and break the loop
      if (received[i] == ',') {
        commaLocation = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    //If a comma is not present, its location variable equals 0,
    //sincerely we just collect all the chars between the parentheses
    //to the 'argument1' variable and send it.
    if (commaLocation == 0) {
      Firmata.sendString("61 passed");
      for (int i = 5; i < ; i++) {
        argument1[(i - 5)] = received[i];
      }


      argument1[strlen(argument1)] = '\0'; //Either this is executed or not, the outcome doesn't change 

      Firmata.sendString(argument1); //This very command doesn't work. It just does not send anything. 
                                     //Looks like 'argument1' is empty, but I'm awfully sure that it must 
                                     //not be empty. Anyway, the 'argument1' does not show up in the client
    }

    //If there is a comma present, then write chars before the comma
    //to 'argument1', and after the comma - to 'argument2'
    if (commaLocation != 0) {
      Firmata.sendString("77 passed");
      //let's write what is before the comma:
      for (int i = 5; i < commaLocation; i++) {
        argument1[i - 5] = received[i];
        Firmata.sendString("81 iterator");
      }

      //let's write what's after the comma;
      char argument2[5];
      for (int i = (commaLocation + 1); i < (strlen(received)); i++) {
        argument2[(i - (commaLocation + 1))] = received[i];
        Firmata.sendString("87 iterator");
      }
      
      argument1[strlen(argument1)] = '\0'; //Either this is executed or not, the outcome doesn't change 
      argument2[strlen(argument2)] = '\0'; 

      Firmata.sendString(argument1); //Not working
      Firmata.sendString(argument2); //Not working
    }
  }
}


void sysexCallback(byte command, byte argc, byte *argv) {
  Firmata.sendSysex(command, argc, argv);
}


void setup() {
  Firmata.setFirmwareVersion(FIRMATA_FIRMWARE_MAJOR_VERSION, FIRMATA_FIRMWARE_MINOR_VERSION);
  Firmata.attach(STRING_DATA, stringCallback);
  Firmata.attach(START_SYSEX, sysexCallback);
  Firmata.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {
  while (Firmata.available()) {
    Firmata.processInput();
  }
}
```

Expected output:

| What I send | What I receive (excluding the debug messages, `;` stands for newline) |
| --- | --- |
| `DHTt()` | `DHTt` |
| `DHTt(1)` | `DHTt`; `1` |
| `DHTt(1,2)` | `DHTt`; `1`; `2` |

Real output:

| What I send | What I receive (excluding the debug messages) |
| --- | --- |
| `DHTt()` | `DHTt` *as long as there are no arguments, there are no problems. But the arguments are necessary for my task* |
| `DHTt(1)` | `DHTt` *the argument are not sent* |
| `DHTt(1,2)` | `DHTt` *two arguments are not sent neither* |

Comment: `strlen(argument1)` tells you the index of the first `'\0'` char, so that line doesn't make sense. This would be a lot simpler if you used pointers to the char array so that you can easily set/change a start point (for example with `recPtr = strchr(received, ',')`) instead of skipping over offsets. Look for helpful tools in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/

Comment: @DanDavis, isn't the cstring equivalent to the Arduino `String` struct, neither the character array?

Comment: Also, please pinpoint which concrete line of the code?

Comment: They're probably referring to any of the lines that take the form `x[strlen(x)] ='\0';`  At best `x` contains a valid string and this line is unless since it just puts a null terminator where one already exists.  If `x` is not a valid c-string, useless is the best outcome you can hope for, but not the only one.  You are going this with `argument1` in two places.  `argument2` in one place.  It seems like it would be good to just spend some time learning about strings outside of the context of your project.  You can play in a desktop environment and transfer over what you learn.

Comment: What does your client (the PC) do with the string? Do you use a library there or did you write the client yourself?

Comment: @pmf, everything my client program does is to accept a string provided by the user and then send it to the Arduino. More information can be found on [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/81238/firmata-strings-sent-from-the-computer-become-damaged-after-arduino) question.

Comment: @dandavis, `strchr` is making the `81 line` loop lose mind. Is a `pointer` which `strchr` returns saveable to a `byte` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Firmata.sendString` does not send anything to the client in two cases:

- If the message is empty;
- **If the message does not contain the `\0` terminator in it**.

In this case, while you're sending `methodName`, you're manually assigning the terminator to the string; and the sender works:

```cpp
methodName[4] = '\0';
```

The only thing necessary to do to solve this argument problem is making each `char` variable end with a null terminator. Here you can see the solved code:

```cpp
#include <Firmata.h>

//setup() and loop() won't be here, there are no changes in them

unsigned long charIndex(const char * findIn, unsigned int symbol) {
  //Find 'symbol' in char array 'findIn'. Unlike
  //strchr(), returns unsigned long or 0 if 'symbol' not found
  
  char * pointer = strchr(findIn, symbol);
  if (pointer != NULL) return (pointer - findIn);
  if (pointer == NULL) return 0;
}


void stringCallback(char *received) {
  //Let's declare all the necessary variables
  char methodName[5];
  char argument1[5];
  char argument2[5];
  int commaLocation = 0;
  int lasti;

  byte nullTerminatorIndex = strlen(received); //For understanding

  //If the received string doesn't match the strings' syntax,
  //send an error message
  if (!(received[4] == '(' && strlen(received) <= 15)) {
    Firmata.sendString("ERR;");
    return;
  }

  //Let's take the 0-3 chars in the string and send it back.
  //It's probably the command name
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    methodName[i] = received[i];
  }
  methodName[4] = '\0'; //**The compiler doesn't add terminators automatically**.
  Firmata.sendString(methodName); //send it
  //This string is being sent without problems.


  //If there is some arguments in the string,
  //it is detectable if the string char 5 is not ')'/
  if (received[5] != ')') {
    //Lent's find out if the input string has a `comma`
    //inside the parentheses. If it does, it means that
    //there are two arguments in the string.

    Firmata.sendString("46 passed");    
    if (charIndex(received, ',') != 0) commaLocation = charIndex(received, ',');

    //If a comma is not present, its location variable equals 0,
    //sincerely we just collect all the chars between the parentheses
    //to the 'argument1' variable and send it.
    if (commaLocation == 0) {
      Firmata.sendString("61 passed");
      for (int i = 5; i < (nullTerminatorIndex - 1); i++) {
        argument1[(i - 5)] = received[i];
        lasti = (i - 5);
      }

      argument1[(lasti + 1)] = '\0';
      lasti = 0;

      Firmata.sendString(argument1); 
    }

    //If there is a comma present, then write chars before the comma
    //to 'argument1', and after the comma - to 'argument2'
    if (commaLocation != 0) {
      Firmata.sendString("77 passed");
      //let's write what is before the comma:
      for (int i = 5; i < commaLocation; i++) {
        argument1[i - 5] = received[i];
        lasti = (i - 5);
      }

      argument1[(lasti + 1)] = '\0';
      lasti = 0;

      //let's write what's after the comma;
      char argument2[5];
      for (int i = (commaLocation + 1); i < (nullTerminatorIndex - 1); i++) {
        argument2[(i - (commaLocation + 1))] = received[i];
        lasti = (i - (commaLocation + 1));
      }

      argument2[(lasti + 1)] = '\0';
      lasti = 0;

      Firmata.sendString(argument1);
      Firmata.sendString(argument2); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of your command parser using cstrings and pointers:

```
void parseArgs(char * rec){
  char cmd[32];
  char arg1[32]= {0};
  char arg2[32]= {0};
  char * ptr; // this is a re-usable workhorse pointer
  char * ptrDelim; // another workhorse to split arguments
  
  // first copy all of it to cmd
  strcpy(cmd, rec);
  // find end of command
  ptr = cmd;
  while( isalpha(ptr[0]) ) ptr++;
  ptr[0] = '\0'; // mark end of command string
  
  
  // find first arg
  ptr = strchr(rec, '(')+1; // set ptr to char to right of open paren
  strcpy(arg1, ptr); // copy stuff after open paren to arg1:
  ptr = strchr(arg1, ')');// find max extent of arg1
  if(ptrDelim=strchr(arg1, ',')){
    ptrDelim[0]='\0'; // end arg1's string at delim
    ptrDelim++; // move right one char
    strcpy(arg2, ptrDelim); // copy stuff after comma
    arg2[strlen(arg2)-1] = '\0'; // chop off ")"
  }else{
    ptr[0]='\0';    
  }//end if comma?
  
    
 Serial.println("\nGiven:" + String(rec)+";");   
 Serial.println("Command:" + String( cmd )+";"); 
 Serial.println("Arg1:" + String( arg1 )+";"); 
 Serial.println("Arg2:" + String( arg2 )+";"); 
  
}
```

Examples:

```
parseArgs("CMDn()");
parseArgs("CMDn(arg1)");
parseArgs("CMDn(arg1,arg2)");
```

Comment: Remove the `String()`-having lines after you get done debugging.

Comment: In `if(ptrDelim=strchr(arg1, ',')){` statement, did you mean `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: Also, what does your code do if there is no arguments in the incoming string?

Comment: @Starter: i should have wrapped the expression in parens as the compiler suggested, but it's an intentional two-fer: if the char is not present in the string it returns a falsy null-pointer, and if it finds it, it returns a truthy evaluation _whilst_ assiging the pointer to that char's posistion.

Comment: @Starter: then they will be blank, which you can detect by `if(strlen(arg1))` or `if(arg1[0])` as needed.

Comment: this is not working correctly. When I input `"CMDn(arg1,arg2)"`, I get [this](https://skr.sh/i/140221/UeOzNZHm.jpg); if no args are present, then there is a `)` in `arg1`; if there is only one arg, it is being recorded to `arg1` along with the comma.